# Excel if current time is later than given time then equal to yes

Tags: excel

Needing help with this formula.
What I hope to achieved is that when current time past the shift time then yes, if not then no.
What formula should I use?

[image]

Comment: A time that is later is greater (`>`).

Comment: as @BigBen said, just a greater....Excel takes datetimes as numbers in the background, so a greater datetime, will be a greater number.....

Comment: `=IF(MOD($C$2,1)>MOD(C5,1),"Yes","No")`

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

1. Use this formula in **"C2"**: `=NOW()-TODAY()`
2. Use this formula in **"D5"**: `=IF($C$2>C5,"Yes","No")`
3. Copy the formula down.

I think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try also this one:

[image]

In **Column E** you write `=IF($C$2-D4>0,"Yes","NO")`

Next, copy the formula to other cells in column E.